# Polymer: Getting a ton of 404 errors to bower_components on load

Tags: polymer

For some reason in my Polymer single-page app I'm getting a slew of weird 404 errors (about 50 of them) from bower components. This doesn't affect the functionality; everything works fine, it's just that all the 404 errors are adding several seconds to my load time.

The errors all look like this, and repeat for every folder in the app  (I'd post a screenshot, but don't have enough rep):

GET http://34.196.185.246/bower_components/paper-input/%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF…F%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD/%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%13%EF%BF%BD%7F

You can see for yourself at http://34.196.185.246/ in the Chrome console.

There's a weird script getting inserted into the head at runtime that I think is the culprit:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="2f2a695a6afce2c2d833c706cd677a8e" src="0��?o=3&g=&s=&z=��������/���"></script>
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: i didn't get any in Chrome console

Comment: That's interesting... was the load slow (like 4 - 5 seconds +)?

Comment: the first load took 4-5 seconds then it took 1.5 seconds to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the polymer-cli. The master polymer-cli had a bug related to building an app with iron-ajax, the solution to which (according to the Polymer Git) was to install polymer-cli@next. This got rid of the iron-ajax problems but introduced the new errors.

The solution for now was to raw-deploy (without building) to the web server - this got rid of the 404 issue and another problem with onload events that was also related to the build.

The polymer-cli still seems to be in a rough patch. They updated the master about three days ago and it introduced new errors into an app that was previously working.